# How to use correctly setFormula in App Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a problem to use correctly setFormula in app script, i tried to use setFormula in a indeterminated range cells but I do not know how to specify that the range of rows be increased and it is not just a specific range. The script that I try to make is a condition in which if in a range of cells there is information, then put the formula in a cell.

```
function formulas() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var rows = activeSheet.getMaxRows();

  for(var  i=7; i <= rows; i++){
    var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();

     if(workingCell != ""){
       activeSheet.getRange(i, 4).setFormula("=$B$5"); //this is fine
       activeSheet.getRange(i, 5).setFormula("=((100/H7)*I7)/100"); //but this not
  }
 }
}
```

how can I do it so if it's row 8 is `(" = ((100 / H8) * I8) / 100 ")` and so on.

**EDIT**
The problem is that I try to apply it to many cells and that the rows that I add will increase according to the row in which I am placing the formula ... If a formula is added in row D9 and D10 , then The range is H9, I9 and H10, I10

Comment: Whats the error message you're getting if there is one?

Comment: If it works, but the problem is that I try to apply it to many cells and that the rows that I add will increase according to the row in which I am placing the formula ... If a formula is added in row `D9` and `D10` , then The range is `H9, I9` and `H10, I10`.

Comment: If understand you correctly this should work: `activeSheet.getRange(i, 5).setFormula("=((100/H" + i + ")*I" + i + ")/100");`

Comment: @Nicolas Works!! Thank you very much friend, what I was trying to do was add another for and trying to remove the setFormula, I did not see that the solution was in the same way I had created, Thank you very much.

Comment: @Nicolas Put your answer so I can upVote it as an answer that helped me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest "fix" , as pointed out in a comment, is to concatenate your `i` loop variable into the formula, like this:

```
function formulas() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1");
  var rows = activeSheet.getLastRow(); //maxRows consider blank rows, you don't need those

  for(var i=7; i <= rows; i++){
    var workingCell = activeSheet.getRange(i, 3).getValue();

     if(workingCell != ""){
       activeSheet.getRange(i, 4).setFormula("=$B$5");
       activeSheet.getRange(i, 5).setFormula("=((100/H" +i+ ")*I" +i+ ")/100");
     }
  }
}
```

Anyway, this function executes too many gets and sets against the spreadsheet, and this will perform poorly as your sheet grows. You should try to minimize all your sets and gets by issuing them in bulk, that is, against a bigger range rather than cell-by-cell.

Your use-case has a problem with this approach because you have some blank spots in your range (when `workingCell` is blank). If setting a "blank" formula for those values is not an issue for you, then you can speed your script greatly by using this:

```
function formulas() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet 1"); //not necessarily active
  var workingCells = sheet.getSheetValues(7, 3, -1, 1); //-1 == lastRow
  var r1c1formulas = [];
  for (var i=0; i < workingCells.length; i++){
     if (workingCells[i][0] != "") {
       r1c1formulas.push(['=R5C2', '=((100/R[0]C[3])*R[0]C[4])/100']);
     } else
       r1c1formulas.push(['=""','=""']);
  }
  sheet.getRange(7, 4, workingCells.length, 2).setFormulasR1C1(r1c1formulas);
}
```

The 2nd "trick" is to use the formulas in R1C1 notation instead of regular A1 style. Check the [setFormulaR1C1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setFormulaR1C1(String)) documentation here.

The R1C1 notation may seem daunting at first but is rather simple, I'd say it is simpler then the 'A1' one. I'll try to summarize it here. `R` is the row number, and `C` column, and in front of the letter you have the row and column numbers (instead of letter). So `=$B$5` is written as `=R5C2`.

The last thing different is the relative reference. In the `A1` notation you just don't place the '$' signs. Which is not really intuitive and not all that flexible when you're trying to set a bunch of formulas at once (exactly your use-case). Because on the A1 the relative formula is a different formula, the references are different `=B1` is not the same as `=C1` (which could be "the same" **if** set on two cells in the same row and consecutive columns).

Anyway, on the R1C1 notation the relative reference is counted as number of rows and columns from the cell that is the reference.

So, when you set the formula `=H7*I7` to cell `E7`, you count that `H` is 3 columns ahead of `E` and `I` 4. And it is all on the same row, so zero row difference. Lastly, to write a relative reference you wrap the number in `[]`. Therefore `=H7 * I7` on `E7` becomes `=R[0]C[3] * R[0]C[4]`.

Comment: The truth is that you have a lot of reason, in the method I was using I executed many times the `get and set` thanks for your help, I still do not understand very well that the formula R1C1 notation but I understood the process, Thank you very much Henrique.

Comment: Tried to add an explanation about the R1C1, hope it helps

Comment: I already understood how it works thank you very much, I just have another small question, how do I do to put the formulas in different columns? I try to separate them and put the formulas in different columns but not works.

Comment: I couldn't quite understand your question.. we are putting formulas in different columns here. Anyway, it is probably best for you to open another Stackoverflow question then ;-)

Comment: Don't worry, I already solved it with your answer, anyway, thanks very much for your help =D